# Formatting date and time in php

Tags: php, mysql

The date of the posted comment appears as

`Aug 21, 2011 05:33`

Using `$v.date_nice` to fetch the date time string from database table, but i want to have "at" in between the date and time,

`Aug 21, 2011 at 05:33`

Comment: which language? Whats the problem?

Comment: If you don't provide more context to this question, it will be closed quite soon.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, you can try the [date](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function. For example:

```
echo date('M d, Y \a\t H:i', strtotime('Aug 21, 2011 05:33'));
// output: Aug 21, 2011 at 05:33
```

Within smarty, you can use [date_format](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.date.format)

If you have access to the timestamp, you'll want to use that instead of strtotime.

Comment: all non 'date' representations need to have a `\\` in front of them as @webbiedave shows.

Comment: but the date appearing is dyanamic

Answer (score 0):

You can either use string functions to add the 'at' in between date and time like:

```
$ntime = substr($v.date_nice,0,12).' at '.substr($v.date_nice,12,4);
```

OR

You can construct the time again by first converting the string to a Unix Time stamp with [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), and then you can recreate any type of string you want using [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Computationally 1st one will be better.

```
$tstamp = strtotime($v.date_nice);
$ntime  = date('M d, Y \a\t H:i', $tstamp );
```